# modelling of solar cell: offset in short-circuit current

Tags: solar-cell, simulation, ltspice, spice, modeling

I am trying to simulate the IV curve of a solar cell in reverse and forward bias. I have used bishop equation that you can see in the following picture.

[image]

The mathermatical model is in good accordance with measurement. However, when I simulate it in SPICE, I have an offset in current which I think is related to the way I have added the leakage part.

[image]

Here is my SPICE code and the equivalent circuit. I will be thankful to have help for correction.

[image: Equivalent circuit regarding to the equation]

```
.param a=1.987261e-01
.param b=2.741757
.param Vbr=-1.865206e+01

.MODEL diode1 D(is={3.71896e-10}, n=1, xti=3)
.MODEL diode2 D(is={1.178667e-05}, n=2, xti=3)

Iphoto 0 internal 8.05
D1 internal 0 diode1 
D2 internal 0 diode2 
Rsh internal n1 92.3597
G1 0 n1 value={1+a*pow((1-(V(internal)/ Vbr),-1*b))}
Rs output internal 0.00252

.dc Vbias -18 1 0.01
```

Comment: I'd say that is more than just an offset - the entire curve is slightly different. Are you sure the parameters entered are correct? If you could draw a schematic with the intended components, I could try to replicate it using LTspice.

Comment: Dear rdtsc
I was not available for a while. Thanks for your comment. I have added the equivalent circuit in the main post. looking forward to see your result. Greets

Comment: While simulating this circuit in LTspice, I get the same curve you get, along with *"Questionable use of curly braces in "b1 0 n002  i={1+{a}*pow(1-(v(inter)/{vbr}),-{b})}"*  **Error: undefined symbol in: "1+(a)*pow(1-([v](inter)/(vbr)),-(b))"**. LTspice definitely can use node voltages in arbitrary sources (the documentation agrees) so I am unsure why it is not working properly. But the issue seems to be with G1 and the "internal" value. I will look at it further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I am sure that there is no problem regarding to the internal node but I am agree that the problem might come from G1 source. Looking forward to hear from you. Greets

Comment: The error in curly braces was due to the outermost set, not the V(internal). As far as I can tell, LTspice and SPICE modeling of (just the leakage current function) is correct. Is your Matlab equation *just* this shunt resistance formula, or the complete formula including \$S_1\$, \$S_2\$, \$N_1\$, \$N_2\$, and \$V_t\$? Note that the text reads \$E(V)=\$ (implying a voltage), but then says it is a current source. Using G1 as a current source, the curve looks exactly like yours. Using "G1" as a voltage source however, produces a curve more like Matlab. It is better, but does not match Matlab.

Comment: Also just note that there are two power functions in LTspice (and likely SPICE as well.) `pow(x,y)` is the real part of x**y, e.g., pow(-1,.5)=0, not i. And `pwr(x,y)` is abs(x)**y. This didn't make any difference in this simulation, but just be aware that two versions may exist.

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49416397/SolarPanel2.png) is a link to an LTspice simulation using G1 as a voltage source. The curve is better, but still incorrect.